# Evaluating definite integral $\int_ 3^6 \frac1{\sqrt{27+6x-x^2}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate the following definite integral.

$ \int _{ 3 }^{ 6 }{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 27+6x-{ x }^{ 2 } }  }  } \quad dx $

I can't figure out how to complete the square.

Comment: $ 27+(6x-x^2) $ ?

Comment: Perhaps write $$27 - (x^2 - 6x)$$ instead. How would you deal with just $x^2 - 6x$?

Comment: Also, on a different note: Please use titles that describe your problem; your last three questions have identical vague titles, and so do the previous three.

Comment: I got it. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you give me an example of title that describe the problem well for this one ?

Comment: "Completing the square in the integral $\int ....$," perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the relevant term as

$$27 - (x^2 - 6x)$$

The usual procedure for $x^2 + bx$ is to add $(b/2)^2$; in this case, $b = 6$ and we add $9$. This leads us to
\begin{align*}
27 - (x^2 - 6x) &= 27 - (x^2 - 6x + 9) + 9 \\
&= 36 - (x - 3)^2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Write

$$\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 27+6x-{ x }^{ 2 } }  } = \frac{1}{6\sqrt{1-\frac{\left(x-3\right)^2}{36}} }$$

And subsitute 
$$x = 3 + u$$